# Error: .htaccess code returning "exceeded internal redirect limit"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, block

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sitetoblock.com [NC]
>
> RewriteRule .* - [F]

Currently it's giving me an error on my site that reads

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

I've found the code several places online telling me it's fine, so what am I doing wrong?

Edit: the rest of the file reads as follows:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/javascript

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 2 days"

ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 2 days"

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 5 minutes"

ExpiresByType text/plain "now plus 5 minutes"

# Block site

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sitetoblock\.com [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: This rule is probably not causing `exceeded internal redirect limit`. Do you have other rules as well?

Comment: I added the rest of the file above - thanks!